# 2300 request to mysql using php takes 2 hours , how to optimize

Tags: php, mysql, rss

am working on a news paper project but without Rss Feed, so i was Compelled to make it's feed programatically  using php , so i have 2300 process of processing pages and inserting in Mysql the results of the processing ,

so the technique i used is to process every single page and then insert it's contents in mysql , it's working good but some times i got "MySQL server gone" ,

i tried to process 30 page and insert them in one request but it stop's after some time

so i am asking about any way to optimize this processing to reduce the time used in ?!

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Your batch insert approach is correct and likely to help. You need to find out why it stops after some time like you say.

It is likely the php script timing out. Look for [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on your php.ini file to make sure it's high enough to allow for the script to finish.

Also, make sure your mysql config allows for a [large enough packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) because you're sending large batches which may be large.

Hope that helps!

Comment: something else to check is max connections.

Comment: thanks for ur answer , max_execution_time :30 in php.ini and i have no access to modify it , and am using in my script set_time_limit(10000); , but the process working for 2 hours with no stop if am processing and inserting every single page , if i tried 30 pages it stop's

Comment: What you can do is modify your php script so that instead of calling mysql directly, it writes all the sql statements to a file. Once the file is ready, you can import it from the command line mysql -uuser -ppasword DATABASE_NAME < text_file_name.sql

Comment: Also, if this is a recurring task you could also limit your script to a specific number of rows. E.g. 1 to 100 and cron it to run every X minutes.

Comment: so , how can i "import it from the command line mysql -uuser -ppasword DATABASE_NAME < text_file_name.sql " from php , my process can be every 6-3 hours , so it have to be automated

Comment: @Yahia, @JuanD is correct. mysql> `database_name < text_file_name.sql` works in the same way as `\. text_file_name.sql`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenties of reasons why "MySQL server has gone away". [Take a look](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

Anyway, it is strange that you load the WHOLE pages. Usually RSS feed implies that you put there just a subject and some text snippet. I'd create RSS feed as simple XML file so it is not necessary to load data from MySQL on EVERY hit users do. You create news -> regenerate RSS XML file, you wrote new article -> regenerate RSS XML file.

If you still want to prepare your data to be inserted, just create a file with ALL inserts and then load data from this file.

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> \. /tmp/data_to_load.sql
```

Yes! all 2300 at a time ;)

```
$generated_sql = 'insert into Table (c1,c1,c3) values (data1,data2,data3);insert into Table (c1,c1,c3) values (data4,data5,data6);';

$sql_file = '/tmp/somefile';
$fp = fopen($sql_file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $generated_sql, strlen($generated_sql)); // wrote sql script
fclose($fp);

`mysql -u $mysql_username --password=$mysql_password < $sql_file`;
```

Backticks are necessary in the last line!

```
$ mysql -u root test
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A    

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 171                          
Server version: 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5 (Ubuntu)               

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql> create table test (id int(11) unsigned not null primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)                                

mysql> exit
Bye        

$ echo 'insert into test.test values (1); insert into test.test values (2);' > file
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > `mysql -u root < /home/nemoden/file`;
php > exit

$ mysql -u root test
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 180
Server version: 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5 (Ubuntu)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select * from test
    -> ;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, as you can see, it worked perfectly.

Comment: the newspaper doesn't have any rssfeed :( , and also after the processing and inserting process i generate the feed as xml , last thing , i have no access to server , only i have php host with mysql server db

Comment: So, what bothers you in my approach ? :) You already have what you need. You don't need to have ssh access to generate file in /tmp/ dir.

Comment: where i should write this script !?  $ mysql -u root
mysql> \. /tmp/data_to_load.sql

Comment: It'a a mysql shell. If you are on Windows, you can use phpMyAdmin, Mysql Workbench, EMS SQL Manager, etc. \. /path/to/sql/file is a SQL query. Just like SELECT ... or INSERT ...

Comment: my process can be every 6-3 hours , so it have to be automated  , can this way to be automated ?!

Comment: So, to clarify, mysql -u root is how you access mysql server from console. \. /path/ is actual command that executes SQL script. You should write it just like you write your SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs, etc... in the same place

Comment: @Yahia everything should be automated. That's why we write programs and rely on them, right? :) Script will consist of: generation of sql file, executing mysql query. That's it. BUT your file should be on the same server that MySQL is running on (in other words: if you use `localhost` for connection to it).

Comment: great , i think as u mentioned that the tmp file will be some thing link : insert into Table (c1,c1,c3) values (data1,data2,data3);insert into Table (c1,c1,c3) values (data4,data5,data6); , it's ok for now , but how can i insert the file in DB using php script , to make a full automated script  ?!

Comment: ok , the sql file is generated well , and i coped it's contents to SQL in PhpMyAdmin and the data is inserted well , but  i have a problem  and my code return false :( , my code is : $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$Table." (title, description,link,creator,pubDate,enclosure,bigImg,thumbImg,originalimage,originlaImgSize,processedImgSize)VALUES ".$string; 
  $myFile = "tempDB.sql";
$fp = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fp,  $sql, strlen( $sql)); // wrote sql script
fclose($fp);

if (mysql_query($myFile, $conn)) {
echo('==== great! data is loaded =====');
}
else {
echo('==== something went wrong =====');
}

Comment: Because you performed query 'tempDB.sql' to MySQL server :) Of course it is shocked :) Read the code I've wrote closer.

Comment: i think am sucked , my link path is /public_html/dar/tempDB.sql , so how can i but it in if (mysql_query('\. '.$sql_file, $mysql_connection_link)) {
 tried alot but in vain

Comment: Apparently, batch load works only for shell. Every day something new. Ok. I've updated my answer. Now should work.

Comment: after generating file i tried , include('my_config.php');
$file = "tempDB.sql";
'mysql -u $user --password=$pass < $file'; but not working also ?!